# Prevent gcc/libstdc++ from calling terminate on throwing from throw() method

Tags: c++, linux, exception, gcc

If I have a method marked throw(), e.g.

```
 void method() throw()
 {
      // do some stuff, call other functions
 }
```

and yet exception *does* happen inside, gcc will terminate the application (with message "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'xyz'").

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

For example, a command-line switch to ignore throw() stuff or force eh_frame generation. Etc.

Comment: only catch() excheption inside will help...

Comment: So you want a function to be unable to throw exceptions, but be able to throw exceptions?

Comment: I do not control both sides (neither throw() neither throw). Not my code. But I have to deal with this combination.

Comment: If it has be to throw() then you need to catch and deal with all exceptions that happen inside the method.

Comment: I would prefer to find a solution that is simpler than modifying 1000 existing source files. Let's say that I'm just curious to find the solution, just for fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html)?

> `-fno-enforce-eh-specs`
>
> Don't generate code to check for violation of exception specifications at run time. This option violates the C++ standard, but may be useful for reducing code size in production builds, much like defining ``NDEBUG`'. This does not give user code permission to throw exceptions in violation of the exception specifications; the compiler still optimizes based on the specifications, so throwing an unexpected exception results in undefined behavior at run time.

It *doesn't* force generate of EH frames, but it should stop the call to `std::unexpected()` and so might be useful for your case.

As the docs say, "the compiler still optimizes based on the specifications" so e.g. it doesn't help when the call to `method()` can be inlined into the catch site, because the compiler assumes the catch is not needed, because the empty exception spec says no exception will be throw, and so if an exception is thrown it doesn't get caught. If the call to `method()` is not inlinable into the catch site it seems to work, the exception leaves `method()` without calling `std::unexpected()` and can be caught higher up the stack.

**Edit**: This will still call `std::terminate()` even with `-fno-enforce-eh-specs`:

```
void func() throw() { throw ""; }
void func2() { func(); }
int main() { try { func2(); } catch (...) { } }
```

The compiler can see that the call to `func2` only calls a no-throw function, so the `catch` will never be needed and so is optimised away. When the exception is thrown, it isn't caught.

This *does* work with `-fno-enforce-eh-specs` and doesn't terminate:

```
/* func2.cc */
void func() throw();
void func2() { func(); }

/* main.cc */
void func2();
int main() { try { func2(); } catch (...) { } }
```

Here, when compiling `main.cc`, the compiler can't tell whether `func2` is going to throw or not because it has no exception specification and its definition is not visible in `main.cc`, so the `catch` cannot be omitted.  When the exception is thrown it will be caught.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. This code dies: void method() throw(){throw "";} int main(){try{method();}catch(...){}}

Comment: Your suggestion works if exception specification is violated; e.g. if it was throw(std::exception). Unfortunately it still dies in case of throw().

Comment: Apparently you didn't actually read my answer. _As the docs say, "the compiler still optimizes based on the specifications" so e.g. it doesn't help when the call to method() can be inlined into the catch site,_

Comment: It was not inlined, I verified that with objdump -d.

Comment: I said **can be inlined** not is inlined, and that's just an example of when it doesn't help, I'm not going to list every possible case that does or doesn't work. In your case the call to the function is visible to the compiler and the function declaration says it won't throw, so the compiler optimises away the `catch`

Comment: I've added a complete example, understand now?

Comment: I just wanted to say that it does not work, not that it is not useful (I did not know about such flag). I've tried your new example, thanks.

Comment: Strange but if I throw directly from func2(), it still dies, unless I remove throw() from the extern func2() declaration in main.cc. But it works in some cases, at least I'll have to fix less code if I don't find a complete solution, thanks.

Comment: There is no `throw()` on the `func2()` declaration so I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 1):

You can provide your own terminate handler by calling `std::set_terminate` ... however I don't think it's legal to return from there, so the only thing it can really do is terminate somehow.

You can provide your own unexpected exception handler with `std::set_unexpected`: the default one calls `std::terminate` but you can do something different (like logging and swallowing the exception). Whether or not you can recover usefully depends on your program though. Also, I've seen it marked deprecated, so relying on this probably isn't the greatest idea.

Comment: No, there's no possibility to swallow the exception in the set_unexpected handler.